# Внешние ссылки API

Tags: php, javascript, api

Каким образом можно получить список сайтов, у которых есть внешние ссылки на мой сайт? Т.е. я хочу получить все сайты, в которых хоть мельком  упоминается адрес моего сайта.

Comment: использовать специальные сервисы SEO аналитики или воспользоваться поисковиком. В добавок к этому можно сохранять REFERER и узнаете откуда пришел пользователь

Comment: я  изучала API   https://ru.majestic.com/, https://moz.com, https://ru.ahrefs.com/, но все они платные. Есть бесплатные API ?

Comment: Бесплатные врядли

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатно внешние ссылки можно получить через [Яндекс Вебмастер](https://webmaster.yandex.ru). Соответственно предварительно нужно добавить сайт в веб-мастер.

В вебмастере выбрать сайт, нажать *Внешних ссылок на страницы сайта*, далее можно увидеть основные ссылки и скачать все ссылки в виде архива.

**UPD:** Также у вебмастера есть api [Получение информации о внешних ссылках на сайт](https://tech.yandex.ru/webmaster/doc/dg/reference/host-links-docpage/), но я им пока не пользовался.